# How to send system timezone to a servlet using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I want to send system timezone to **servlet** using **javascript** . How could I do it when I submit a button on **JSP** ? .

This is javascript code .

```
<script>
    function dateReturn() {
          var date = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
          return date;
    }
</script>
```

How can I use this script to do above ?

Comment: possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: @Janath : - This isn't a duplication .

Comment: @Janath I want to get whole description of the system timezone and send it to a servlet .

Comment: please refer my below answer for extract timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Read the timezone offset and send it as a separate field or combine date and offset together in 1 item and parse it on server side.

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Read [JavaScript getTimezoneOffset() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) for more information.

Comment: Can you give me example ?

Comment: example of what? how to send data or how to combine Date with TimeZone?

Comment: I want to get whole time zone , including time, date , GMT & so on .

Comment: If I get whole description of timezone , how could I send it to a servlet ?

Comment: In example I've added variable D contains time, date and N keeps Timezone/Offset. You have everything there.

Answer (score 0):

try this for retrieve timezone. you can adjust the substring function for retrieve other details from date object.

```
var d = new Date();
var s = d.toString();
var timezone= s.substring(s.indexOf("(")+1, s.indexOf(")"));
```